# How to Migrating two databases which using Primary key and auto increment value SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key, auto-increment, data-migration

I have 2 databases. Both contain same table designs DB1 and DB2. both having different data. I need to integrate DB2 to DB1. DB1 contain primary keys with auto increment. i need to insert DB2 datas to DB1 top. Means DB1 primary keys = top of DB2+ DB1 id.

ie, if DB1 contains 1,2,3,4,5 and DB2 also contains 1,2,3,4,5. 
when I insert data from DB2 to DB1, the data in DB2 will become 6,7,8,9,10. 
but I need 1,2,3,4,5 for DB2 and 6,7,8,9,10  as DB1 data..

Thanks in advance
Jidhu

Comment: Is this just one table or are there dependant tables using these primary keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query:

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) FROM Db1

SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1 ON
INSERT INTO Db1(Id, Column1, Column2, ...)
SELECT @MaxId+ ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id),
        Column1,
        Column2,
        ...
FROM db2
SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1 OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Mehdi had it close to what you want, but appears to have miss understood exactly what you was asking with a few changes to his code this is easily achievable.

```
    DECLARE @MaxId INT
    SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) FROM Db2 /* changed this to Db2 */

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1 ON

    /* increment all the id's in db1 to the max of db2 plus there current id to allow room for DB2 to enter */
    UPDATE Db1 SET Id = @MaxId + Id 

   /*Now insert all of DB2's values in to DB1 with there original Id's*/
    INSERT INTO Db1(Id, Column1, Column2, ...)
    SELECT  Id
            Column1,
            Column2,
            ...
    FROM db2
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1 OFF
```